# swiftでWAVファイルを読み込みたい

Tags: swift4

拡張子が.wav形式のファイルを読み込みたいのですが、できません。
XcodeはVersion 9.0.1 でswiftはversion 4.0です。

.wavファイルから最終的にデータ部分をIntやFloatのarrayとして取り出したいです。

下記のソースコードは
http://atmarkplant.com/ios-wav-file-read/
をもとに書きました

```
let orgWaveData:NSData = try NSData(contentsOfFile:"/Users/username/Desktop/sample.WAV",options:[])
let subWaveData:NSData = orgWaveData.subdata(with: NSMakeRange(44, orgWaveData.length-44)) as NSData
let sample = malloc(subWaveData.length)
memcpy(sample, subWaveData.bytes, subWaveData.length);
```

また、AudioToolboxを使いできないかと思い、下記のようなコードでも試してみましたが、
resultが-54という結果で、うまく取得できていませんでした。

```
import AudioToolbox

let filePath = "/Users/username/Desktop/sample.WAV"
let url: CFURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: filePath)
var dataPointer:AudioFileID?
let filetype = kAudioFileWAVEType
let result = AudioFileOpenURL(url,.readPermission,filetype, &dataPointer)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`AVAudioFile`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiofile)を使ってみてはいかがでしょうか。

[ネタ元はこちら](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34751294/6541007)ですが、最新版のXcode 10/Swift 4.2に合わせて書き換えています。(申し訳ありませんが、Xcode 9.0.1は手元にありません。それほど大きな書き換えはいらないと思います…。)

```
import Foundation
import AVFoundation

let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/dev/Desktop/sound.wav")
doBlock: do {
    //所定の処理形式でデータを読み込む(16-bit整数、非インターリーブ)
    let file = try AVAudioFile(forReading: url, commonFormat: .pcmFormatInt16, interleaved: false)
    let format = file.processingFormat
    print(format)
    //AVAudioPCMBufferを`file.processingFormat`と同じフォーマットで作成
    guard let buffer = AVAudioPCMBuffer(pcmFormat: format, frameCapacity: 1024) else {
        print("Failed to create AVAudioPCMBuffer")
        break doBlock
    }
    //AVAudioPCMBufferに読み込み
    try file.read(into: buffer)
    //UnsafeBufferPointerに変換する
    var samples: [UnsafeBufferPointer<Int16>] = []
    let channels = Int(format.channelCount)
    for ch in 0..<channels {
        samples.append(UnsafeBufferPointer(start: buffer.int16ChannelData![ch], count: Int(buffer.frameLength)))
    }
    //AVAudioPCMBufferが解放されてしまうと以下の処理が失敗するので、おまじない
    withExtendedLifetime(buffer) {
        //最初の50サンプルを出力してみる
        for i in 0..<50 {
            let index = i * buffer.stride
            for ch in 0..<channels {
                print(samples[ch][index], terminator: " ")
            }
            print()
        }
    }

} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

ご質問中のリンク先記事は、WAVファイルのヘッダが44バイトなんて言い切っていたりして、いまいち信頼性が低いような気がします。私のコードもありとあらゆるWAVファイルで試してみただけではありませんが。

お試しの上、何かお気付きの点があればおしらせください。

Comment: ありがとうございます！解決いたしました。自分の場合は上記のいただいたサンプルコードのURLではなぜかうまくいきませんでした。※もちろん自分の環境用に書き換えております。想定される理由がお分かりであれば教えていただきたいです。自分の場合はファイルをXcodeでcommand+1で出てくるResourceフォルダに移し、URLの宣言をlet audioFileURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "sample", withExtension: "wav")とすることで取得できました。ありがとうございました！元ネタはこちらです。https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30179125/avaudiofile-in-swift-playground-results-in-error-54

Comment: @shin-ichi さん、ご報告ありがとうございます。示された元ネタの方法でうまくいったと言うことはXcode Playgroundでお試しだったのでしょうか。環境やプラットフォームなど、ご質問中にタグなどの形でお示しいただくと、よりご自身の環境に適した回答を得ることにつながります。ちなみに私の回答のコードはmacOS用のCommand Line Toolプロジェクトで動作確認するためのものです。ちょっとしたことはご自身で解決できるようなので、問題ないかもしれませんが、また質問を書かれる際には気にしてみてください。いずれにせよ、なにがしかのお役立てたのなら幸いです。

Comment: ありがとうございます。プラットフォームについてplaygroundとprojectでそのような違いがあると考えもしなかったもので。。。ありがとうございます。大変勉強になりました。

Comment: @shin-ichi さん、iOSに設定されたPlaygroundでは、Simulatorと同じく擬似的なSandbox環境で走るので、外部ファイルのアクセスには強い制限がかかっています。オーディオ関連の機能はmacOSとiOSで違いが少ないので、オーディオファイルに関するちょっとしたAPIの動きを調べる時など、macOS用のプロジェクトでざっくりの動作を調べるなんてことはよくあります。(そのせいで、ついこう言う環境を想定したコードです、と言うのを書き忘れてしまったのですが。)最終的にiOSアプリを作りたいのなら、iOSでも動作確認しておかないといけませんが、Playgroundは動作のかったるいことも多いので、場合によってはmacOSのCommand Line Tooプロジェクトも使われると、いろいろなことを試してみると言う場合の能率があげられるかもしれません。